# How to copy a filtered list to another sheet

Tags: excel

I'am searching for a solution for the following situation:
[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y68Qm.png)

I just want to copy one row from a filterd list to another sheet.
I tryed to mark the table and choose 'only visible cells', then copy the table into the same sheet. When I filter the List, the copy of the table gets filtered to, works well so far. But unfortunately it doesn't work, when I copy the table to another sheet.

Is there a way to solve the problem, maybe without a makro?

Comment: Have you tryed the advanced filter? http://excelsemipro.com/2011/03/copy-data-to-another-worksheet-with-advanced-filter/

Comment: Yes I tryed it, but I doesn't have any criteria. And a 'not NULL' criteria seems not to be legal.

Comment: Use GOTO Special, click on check Visible Cells Only then copy and paste in another sheet

Comment: If you use GOTO special the filter will not show in the new sheet